# click_link not working after assert_select confirms link is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

**Background**

I want to write the following test for my Ruby on Rails application.

1. Log in as user.
2. Visit edit user page.
3. Click link in nav to go to About Us page.
4. Actually visit the About Us page and confirm its the correct template.

The reason is that I found a bug where for the link About Us I have it be referential for '/welcome/about/' and so it goes to /users/welcome/about which doesn't exist.

**My Code**

My test code is as follows:

```
 test 'welcome page from user page works' do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_select "a", { :text=> "About Us" }
    click_on ("About Us")
    assert_template 'welcome/about'
  end
```

**Error Message**

```
 ERROR["test_welcome_page_from_user_page_works", WelcomePageTest, 1.42307711095782]
 test_welcome_page_from_user_page_works#WelcomePageTest (1.42s)
Capybara::ElementNotFound:         Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link or button "About Us"
        test/integration/welcome_page_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:WelcomePageTest>'

Finished in 1.42605s
1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Since there is 1 assertion this makes me think that the assertion the link exists pasts but somehow click_link can't find it?

**EDIT** This was my final code for the test:

```
  test 'welcome page from user page works' do
    log_in_as(@user)
    visit edit_user_path(@user)
    click_on ("About Us")
    assert_template 'welcome/about'
  end
```

Note I also changed the routes to be just hardcoded in:

```
  get     'about'  => 'welcome#about'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For capybara use the `visit` method instead of `get`

`visit edit_user_path(@user)`